# How can I embed a Facebook Like Box in my website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I get the feeling this should be easy but I can't get anything to work.

I've created an app on Facebook for my website. I've set my site URL and made my app public.

According to the instructions I should add this code near the top of my `body`

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.2'
  });
};
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then I can embed plugins like this:

```
<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

When I do this I don't see any content inside the `fb-like` `div`.

I dug a little deeper and it seems that the `sdk.js` file that should be pulled in by the first bit of code is not. Instead the `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` URL returns a `307 Internal Redirect` to `about:blank`.

I've cleared my cache and I've tried this code on `localhost` as well as on my actual domain and I changed the site URL to match.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `//` only works if you are testing it using a web server/accessing the page via HTTP(S) – if you are just opening the HTML document via the file system, you need to replace it with `http://` explicitly.

Comment: I am using HTTP (not file://) but I tried replacing the URL with a straight http:// anyway. No difference I'm afraid, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well then check your browser’s error console, whether anything shows up there. Or show a live example.

Comment: Nothing in the console except a warning about `about:blank` not being a script. There's a live version at www.distorteddecade.com

Comment: Well, on that page I see the Like/Share buttons in the lower left corner …

Comment: dumb question, but do you have an adblocker or other plugin which prevents Facebook URLs from embedding?

Comment: I'm an absolute fool. Why didn't I think of the ad blockers. Thanks Igy, do you want to write your comment up as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case I had the Disconnect Chrome plugin running. It blocks requests to social media sites.

I turned off the blocker plugin and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes helps to run in anonymous mode to check the influence of extensions.